# Matrix Integral Problem, what should I do

Tags: integration, matrix-decomposition

$A$ and $B$ are square matrices

$$\exp(t(A+B))=\exp(tA)+\int_0^t \exp((t-s)A)B\exp(s(A+B))\,\mathrm ds$$

I found it from problem sets. It seems to define a new kind of matrix operation.
I can check its truth when $A,B$ are scalars ($n=1$), but fail to prove it for general cases. The matrices do not commute and I cannot think of a way to do it. 
Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: this might proven using the Baker Haussdorff formula

Comment: It is just a matrix analysis course, not as far as that